# express controller for catch error handling

Tags: node.js, express

How to implement DRY in express's controller? I found I have repeated code for catch function.

```
exports.getUsers = (req, res) => {

  Ad.find({})
  .then(data=>{
    res.json({status:1, data})
  })
  .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send({
          msg: err
      })
  })
}

exports.getUser = (req, res) => {

  User.findOneById({id: res.body.id})
  .then(data=>{
    res.json({status:1, data})
  })
  .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send({
          msg: err
      })
  })
}
```

Most of the time we just want to return the same error object, but in one controller file, we have many of this

```
.catch(err => {
          res.status(400).send({
              msg: err
          })
      })
```

Is there anywhere we can implement that once as middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as a middleware but you can create a function, `sendErrorResponse` which takes `res` and `err` as parameters, like:

```
function sendErrorResponse(res, err) {
    return res.status(400).send({
              msg: err
    })
}
```

Then use it as:

```
User.findOneById({id: res.body.id}).then(data=>{
    res.json({status:1, data})
})
.catch(err => sendErrorResponse(res, err))
```

If you want, you can move `sendErrorResponse` to a seperate file and require it in multiple controllers.

Comment: not much difference, if I have 100 controllers I'll have 100 of `.catch(err => sendErrorResponse(res, err))
`

Comment: Not really, it's better some because if you want to change your key from `msg` to `message`, you will only have to do it in one place. In fact, using methods and subroutines is perfectly OK in DRY because your business logic is encapsulated

Comment: make sense, so there's no such thing as a global error handler for all controllers and routes?

Comment: You can catch all uncaught errors and unhandled rejections, but the problem is passing the `res` object into the handler.

Comment: how would you do it in ur real project? have catch on every controllers as well?

Comment: I would and I have. Better to be safe too.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap every route with a middleware that catches errors.

```
const errorHandler = fn => (req, res, next) => {
  Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next))
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send({ msg: err.message });
    });
};

app.post('/users', errorHandler(getUsers));
```

But with this approach every error will be send with status 400 and you may also expose critical information. I recommend to subclass Error with custom Errors e.g. BadRequestError and throw this error inside your controllers and change the middleware like this:

```
const errorHandler = fn => (req, res, next) => {
  Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next))
    .catch(err => {
      if (err.name === 'BadRequestError') {
        res.status(400).send({ msg: err.message });
      } else {
        // log the error
        res.status(500).send({ msg: 'Internal Server Error' })
      }
    });
};
```

As a nice side effect: By wrapping every endpoint with an `errorHandler` your application gets very robust as you will always send a response and never get a timeout on the client side if your code fails.

Comment: so in every route I have to do this `app.post('/users', errorHandler(getUsers));
`? Can't go one level up? I have plenty of routes too

Comment: You can build your routes dynamically as described in [this](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/examples/route-map/index.js) example. And change the map function to wrap all your controllers. If you have plenty routes it's way more readable aswell.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send errors simply you can use below code in your catch block. status could be set to desired status code.

```
res.status(200).send(error);
```

It would return an errors object that contains all errors. Below is example payload

```
{
    "errors": {
        "description": {
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "message": "Path `description` is required.",
            "properties": {
                "message": "Path `description` is required.",
                "type": "required",
                "path": "description"
            },
            "kind": "required",
            "path": "description"
        }
    },
    "_message": "Posts validation failed",
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "message": "Posts validation failed: description: Path `description` is required."
}
```